# handling back button android

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-button

I have a problem while hitting the back button on an activity, in particular, the back button on the activity closes the application and destroys all the activities, I want to go back in the stack, and in the previously called activity when hitting the back button.

Here is my code:

```java
ChatToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chat_bar_layout);
setSupportActionBar(ChatToolBar);
ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View action_bar_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(action_bar_view);
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ChatActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity" />
```

I also tried:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ProfileActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Where should be the problem?

Comment: do you mean the top parent/UP button or the bottom back button ?

Comment: Can you check if you activities have `History` set to `false`

Comment: i mean both the buttons, the back and the top buttons cose the application. @Ali how can i see if activity has history set to false?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it with this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            SendUserToMainActivity();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add button back in action bar

in mainfest.xml

```
<activity .ActivityB" >
<meta-data
 android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
 android:value=".ActivityA" />
```

Comment: the back button is already set programmatically with setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)... this will display a back arrow in the tool bar, on the left upper corner, but the arrow if pressed closes the application

Comment: i tried this in the manifest         <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ProfileActivity" />
        </activity>   but it doesn't work